# JS Mortgage Calculator: Adding Commas to Input Field Not Formatting Correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a mortgage calculator but I wanted to add the commas into the form fields. This code came from another answer and it works well for the most part. The issue is that any number over 1,000,000 begins to format strangely. I'm a novice with JS so any help is appreciated.

This is the flow:
1. User types in data
2. JS reformats with commas
3. When the user calculates the commas are stripped out before the calculation
4. The monthly payment is returned

**HTML**

```
<h5 type="text" id="pmt" name="mPmt">See your monthly payment</h5>

<div class="mortgagecalculator">
<form action="">

<label>Interest Rate (%)<input type="text" id="apr" name="APR"> 
</label>

<label>Loan Term (Years)<input type="text" id="trm" name="APR"> 
</label>

<label>Down Payment <input type="text" id="dPmt" name="dPmt" 
onkeyup="addComma(this);">
</label>

<label>Home Price <input type="text" id="amt" name="amt" 
onkeyup="addComma(this);"></label>

<input type="button" id="sbt" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" id="rst" value="Reset Form">
<ula="reset"="reset"></ula="reset"="reset">
</form></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var term;
var apr;
var amt;
var mPmt;
var dPmt;


window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementById("apr").focus();
  document.getElementById("sbt").onclick = getValues;
};

//use toFixed(2) to reduce the decimal places of mPmt. Use it on the 
mortgage payment output.

function getValues()
{
  term = document.getElementById("trm").value;
  apr = document.getElementById("apr").value;
  amt = document.getElementById("amt").value;
  dPmt = document.getElementById("dPmt").value;
  apr /= 1200;
  term *= 12;
  mPmt = calculatePayment().toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("pmt").innerHTML ="$" + mPmt +"/mo.";
};

//applied .replace to the amt and dPmt to remove commas before calculating

function calculatePayment()
{   
    var payment = (amt.replace(",", "")-dPmt.replace(",", ""))*(apr * Math.pow((1 + apr), term))/(Math.pow((1 + apr), term) - 1);
return payment;
}

//this adds commas to the form field while typing but I just ripped it from Stack Overflow so I have no idea how the formula works.

        function addComma(txt) {
txt.value = txt.value.replace(",", "").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}


</script>
```

**TL:DR Corrected JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var term;
var apr;
var amt;
var mPmt;
var dPmt;


window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementById("apr").focus();
  document.getElementById("sbt").onclick = getValues;
};

//use toFixed(2) to reduce the decimal places of mPmt. Use it on the 
mortgage payment output.

function getValues()
{
  term = document.getElementById("trm").value;
  apr = document.getElementById("apr").value;
  amt = document.getElementById("amt").value;
  dPmt = document.getElementById("dPmt").value;
  apr /= 1200;
  term *= 12;
  mPmt = calculatePayment().toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("pmt").innerHTML ="$" + mPmt +"/mo.";
};

//applied .replace to the amt and dPmt to remove commas before calculating

function calculatePayment()
{   
    var payment = (amt.replace(/,/g, "")-dPmt.replace(/,/g, ""))*(apr * Math.pow((1 + apr), term))/(Math.pow((1 + apr), term) - 1);
return payment;
}

//this adds commas to the form field while typing 

        function addComma(txt) {
txt.value = txt.value.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the addComma function, your replace is only going to replace the first comma it comes across.  You need to have it remove every comma in the string.  Try this after "txt.value =":

```
txt.value.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
```

The g flag means global, so it will grab all the commas in the string instead of just the first.

Comment: Worked perfectly! thank you so much. I also applied this to the replace in my equation to scrub the commas before calculation which resolved a separate issue.

Comment: Glad to help.  You said you were new to this, so if you haven't already done so, take a look at regex101.com.  It's where you can plug in regular expressions (i.e. the stuff in the second replace that says "/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g") and it will decipher what each symbol is doing.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again. I'd like to to actually understand this stuff versus just copying answers, so I'll definitely have a look.